# Property 'Font' is 'ReadOnly' vb.net for new Font

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What is wrong in my code

```
    Dim privateFonts As New System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection()
    privateFonts.AddFontFile("C:\Documents and Settings\somefont.ttf")
    Dim font As New System.Drawing.Font(privateFonts.Families(0), 12)
    LBL_Test.Font = font
```

I have error on line: LBL_Test.Font = font

LBL_test is standard label like that:

```
<asp:Label ID="LBL_Test" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Are you certain that is the exact error message (I assume you mean "Property") and that it occurs on that line?  The `Font` property of `Label` is not read-only but the _properties_ of a `Font` object are.  Are you trying to change the size or some other property somewhere?

Comment: Nop, is all i have in my Load and yes is "Property"

Comment: LBL_Test.Font = font get me that error

Comment: What exactly is `LBL_Test`?

Comment: <asp:Label ID="LBL_Test" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

Answer (score 2):

Since you're in a web page, you can't use a `Font` object like you'd do in WinForms or WPF, and indeed [the documentation shows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.font(v=vs.110).aspx) that the `Font` property is readonly:

> `Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Font As FontInfo`

Instead, you're working with CSS and HTML styling, so you can style it using those sorts of properties, for example:

```
LBL_Test.Font.Name = "Verdana"
LBL_Test.Font.Bold = true
```

To do this sort of styling, you're often better off adding a CSS class and using stylesheets to do the styling, eg:

```
LBL_Test.CssClass = "MyClass"
```

Or in your markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="LBL_Test" CssClass="MyClass" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

and then in a stylesheet:

```
.MyClass {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold
}
```

etc.

Having said all that, it looks like you want to use some sort of custom font.  In order to do that, you'll either need to have it installed on the computer the browser is running on, or instead use [a web font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyCustomFont";
    src: url("http://your-server/somefont.ttf");
}

.MyClass {
    font-family: "MyCustomFont"
}
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to use my Font because i need to transform that text in Code Bar. How i use in css my Font like name.ttf?

Comment: @Vladut Was just adding a webfont example, does that help?

Comment: I try just like that, o second

Answer (score 1):

try

```
LBL_Test.Styles.Add("font-family", "MyCustomFont")
```